# Vuetify Brithday Picker not working. Error: Property or method "on" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I use birthday picker on my Vuetify form. All other picker are working fine. But when Im adding Birthday Picker, I got this error.

**Property or method "on" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.**

Cant understand where I made the mistake. I used exactly the same code that provided by Vuefity.

Here is my code Details

```
<template>
  <v-menu
    ref="menu"
    v-model="menu"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    transition="scale-transition"
    offset-y
    min-width="290px"
  >
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="date"
        label="Birthday date"
        prepend-icon="event"
        readonly
        v-on="on"
      ></v-text-field>
    </template>
    <v-date-picker
      ref="picker"
      v-model="date"
      :max="new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)"
      min="1950-01-01"
      @change="save"
    ></v-date-picker>
  </v-menu>
</template>   

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      date: null,
      menu: false,
    }),
    watch: {
      menu (val) {
        val && setTimeout(() => (this.$refs.picker.activePicker = 'YEAR'))
      },
    },
    methods: {
      save (date) {
        this.$refs.menu.save(date)
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You have an attribute `v-on` which is usually allocated an event, like `v-on:click` and you reference a function also called `on` – are you sure you didn't mean to change this? i.e. rather than `v-on="on"` it should say `v-on:change="save()"`

Comment: I tried  rather than v-on="on" it should say v-on:change="save()"  but not working

Comment: Just like v-bind="prop" lists all properties you could bind under their own name, v-on="on" is used by vuetify to attach all events provided in the on in the slot props.

Answer (score 0):

Taken and modified from vuetify example:

```
<v-menu
  ref="menu"
  v-model="menu"
  :close-on-content-click="false"
  :return-value.sync="date"
  transition="scale-transition"
  offset-y
  min-width="290px"

  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <v-text-field
      v-model="date"
      label="Birthday Picker"
      prepend-icon="event"
      readonly
      v-on="on"
    ></v-text-field>
  </template>
  <v-date-picker v-model="date" @change="$refs.menu.save(date)" no-title scrollable>
  </v-date-picker>
</v-menu>
```

Shouldn't have removed the `:return-value.sync="date"` or `this.$refs.menu.save()` doesn't do anything. I'm not sure how this would trigger 'on is not defined on this instance' error, trying to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error with v-menu in Vuetify.
What I did is just add `on` in `data` as following:

```
...

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      on: undefined
    }),
    ...
  }
</script>
```